# Split string by "],["

Tags: regex, string, split

I know one back slash `/` can be used to escape some special characters like `(`, `.` and double back slash `//` can be used to escape special characters in a string directly.

I want to split:

`"[[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0]]"`

by `],[` between each sub array.

What should I do if I want to get all the sub arrays by splitting them to be `"[[0,0,1,0,0", "0,0,0,0,0","0,0,0,1,0","1,1,0,1,1", "0,0,0,0,0]]"` first.
If you have better idea on how to convert them directly into sub arrays including numbers only like `"0,0,1,0,0", "0,0,0,0,0","0,0,0,1,0","1,1,0,1,1", "0,0,0,0,0"` that will be even better.

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: Neither of those are backslashes. What is the code you’re using?

Comment: I want to split the above string by "],["

Comment: @ZhenXu are you tried to build a 2d array out of the string?

Comment: @ShanuGupta, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both `[` and `]` at special characters in `regex` you need to escape them.

you can try with below:

```
str.split("\\],\\[");
```

Test code:

```
String str="[[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0]]";
String[] strs = str.split("\\],\\[");
for(String s:strs){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output result:

```
[[0,0,1,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0
1,1,0,1,1
0,0,0,0,0]]
```

If you want to remove the duplicate `[[` and `]]`,just add below codes before split:

```
str = str.substring(2);
str = str.substring(0, str.length()-2);
```

---

Updated answer,if you want to eliminate all the brackets in between and at both ends by `regex`,you write regex like `\[?\[((\d,)+\d)` then fetch the first group of each match record data, below is the code:

```
String str = "[[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0]]";
String regex = "\\[?\\[((\\d,)+\\d)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

The output is

```
0,0,1,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,1,0
1,1,0,1,1
0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: any idea on how to convert them directly to 2D array directly

Comment: @ZhenXu java8 stream is an option for you,wait minute

Comment: I would be better if you can just use one regex to handle them, I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: You mean you want to use an regex to create a 2D array directly?

Comment: I mean using a regex to eliminate all the brackets in between and at both ends.

Comment: @ZhenXu Updated my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174641/discussion-between-lucumt-and-zhen-xu).

Answer (score 1):

Your input is valid JSON, so I suggest using a JSON parser.

The code would look like this:

```
import javax.json.*;

JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader("[[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0]]"));
JsonArray array = jsonReader.readArray();
jsonReader.close();
System.out.println("Array #2: " + array.getJsonArray(1)); // should give [0,0,0,0,0]
System.out.println("Array #3, 4th value: " + array.getJsonArray(2).getInt(3)); // should give 1
```

Comment: This is very useful. I am trying to convert this JsonArray to a primitive type 2D array. Any idea?

Comment: Try something like this:

    JsonArray external = jsonReader.readArray();
    List<List<Integer>> listOfList = IntStream.range(0, externalArray.length())
        .mapToObj(i -> {
            JsonArray internalArray = externalArray.getJsonArray(i);
            IntStream.range(0, internalArray.length()).mapToObj(j -> internalArray.getInt(0)).collect(Collectors.toList())
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

It's not using a primitive array but I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the `String` to convert into a `2d-Array`, you can use below functions that takes the `String` and returns the `2d-Array` of `int`s:

```
private static int[][] getMatrixFromString(String arrayStrinng) {
    String arrayString = arrayStrinng.substring(1, arrayStrinng.length() - 1);

    String[] splitMajor = arrayString.split("],");
    int rowCount = splitMajor.length, colCount = 0;
    int[][] matrix = new int[rowCount][];


    for (int row = 0; row < splitMajor.length; row++) {
        String[] splitMinor = splitMajor[row].split(",");
        if (colCount == 0) {
            colCount = splitMinor.length;
            matrix = new int[rowCount][colCount];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            if (splitMinor[i].startsWith("["))
                splitMinor[i] = splitMinor[i].substring(1);
            if (splitMinor[i].endsWith("]"))
                splitMinor[i] = splitMinor[i].substring(0, splitMinor[i].length() - 1);

            matrix[row][i] = Integer.parseInt(splitMinor[i]);
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```